# Does the order of the variables in double integral matter?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

Given
$\displaystyle\iint_D x \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$ and D = {$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: -2 \leq x \leq 2, 0 \leq y \leq 2$}

So I have learned that the order doesn't matter but look here:

$$\iint_D x\; \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y= \int_0^2 \left[\frac{x^2}2 \right]_{x=-2}^{x=2} \mathrm{d}y =  \int_0^2 (2-2) \mathrm{d}y = \int_0^2 (0) \mathrm{d}y = c$$

$$\iint_D x\; \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x= \int_{-2}^2 \left[xy \right]_{y=0}^{y=2} \mathrm{d}y =  \int_{-2}^2 (2x) \mathrm{d}x = [x^2]_{x=-2}^{x=2}  = 4 - 4 = 0$$

So as you can see I get two different answers, I know since c is a constant it can be 0 but it says that the answer is 0, but it is something I can determine by integrating with respect to x first which means the order somewhat matters?. Assuming I did it correctly, if I get a constant c after integrating do I need to change the order and check wether I get something else? In that case why?

Comment: Where is c coming from? It should be 0. You’re taking the definite integral of the zero function

Comment: Anyway, even if you say $c$ is the antiderivative, note that you have a definite integral so evaluating at endpoints gives you $c-c=0$.

Comment: I think the **Fubini Theorem** of Riemann integral is probably what you are looking for.